# get server time in php - timezone issues

Tags: php, timezone

on shell, my server time is (simple `date` in bash):
Sun Aug 29 10:37:12 EDT 2010

when I run the code `php -r "echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');"` I get: 2010-08-29 10:37:10

but when I execute a php script that has `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` I get a different time- since php thinks the timezone is UTC (server time is EDT).

My php.ini file has no timezone set, and I wouldnt like to change anything- as I have no idea what affect it would have on other sites that run on this server.

Is there a simple way to get the server time- at the timezone that is set for the server?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [php.ini directives](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) manual page, the timezone isn't set by default if you're using a version prior to 5.3. Then if you take a look at the page for [`date_default_timezone_get`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php), it uses the following order for getting the timezone:

```
* Reading the timezone set using the date_default_timezone_set() function (if any)
* Reading the TZ environment variable (if non empty) (Prior to PHP 5.3.0)
* Reading the value of the date.timezone ini option (if set)
* Querying the host operating system (if supported and allowed by the OS)
```

UTC is the default if all of those fail, so that's probably a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The server should **always**  have a timezone specified in the `php.ini` file. PHP 5.3 even raises notices if that's not the case and the `DateTime` extension will throw exceptions if you attempt to build objects without explicitly specifying a timezone (with a `DateTimezone` object) or having a default one (either through `date.timezone` or `date_default_timezone_set`).

By what you're describing, the most likely scenarios are:

- Different php.ini files are being used in the two scenarios. In the first case, no default timezone is specified, so PHP attempts to infer one from the system-wide timezone of the machine.
- The (second) script calls `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Late for the party, but if you want to set the timezone without edit php.ini, you can put in the php code one of these strings:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using date_default_timezone_set()
American timezones can be found here http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php