# Get my system time zone in php

Tags: php, javascript, timezone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guessing User's TimeZone in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498128/guessing-users-timezone-in-php)

How can i get my system current time zone in **php** thanks in advance
I tried this code

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo date('H:i:s');
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo date('H:i:s');
```

but i got

```
**UTC
07:51:52

GMT
07:51:52**
```

also i tried date('Z');
i got

**0**

but my time zone is asia/kolkatta

Comment: you need to provide the $timezone_identifier to the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: can i get timezone without that because my current requirment is depend upon system time

Comment: check it out from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595164/get-server-time-in-php-timezone-issues

Comment: "my system time zone" -- what do you mean by that? Server's timezone?

Comment: @ zerkms:timezone of local machine

Comment: You cannot get the timezone of the remote system (the client, *your* system), because the client does not typically send that information to the server. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @deceze :when iam sending a meeting invite from india(or any other cuntry) the person who is receiving the invite must see the meeting time as london time.Plz help me out

Comment: Then ask each user what timezone he's in. That's pretty standard practice for calendaring software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send all time information as UTC, then if the local machine has its system clock set correctly it can be converted to a local time. There are some functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714180/date-converts-certain-date-strings-to-local-time/10714277#10714277) for converting to and from UTC on a local machine in javascript. Your server should only work in UTC.

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't know anything about server's timezone. **date_default_timezone_get**() function returns value from php.ini or if it was set by **date_default_timezone_set**();

You can get it from command line using [date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_%28Unix%29) on *nix or [tzutil](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/winservergen/thread/afaa73f1-a420-4bdd-accb-6c7994c49193) on Windows.